# Using "today" and "two days before" in date with Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I have the following `WHERE`clause in a query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE IMPORT_DATE between 
     to_date('2018-03-16 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and
     to_date('2018-03-16 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

And I would like to write two new queries:

- One with this same clause but using "today" instead of "2018-03-16".
- Another with the same clause but using "the day before yesterday" (today - 2) instead of "2018-03-16".

How can I do this in Oracle?

Comment: Just FYI, Oracle supports ANSI date literals (as well as timestamp literals) so you should never have to use the `TO_DATE()` function with a static date. Just use, e.g., `DATE'2018-03-16` in lieu of `to_date('2018-03-16 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oracle has no real `DATE` data type and always includes a time, it's usually better to not use `between` for conditions like that, but to use `>=` together with `<` compared to midnight the next day.

To find the rows from "today" use:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE import_date >= trunc(sysdate) 
  AND import_date < trunc(sysdate) + 1;
```

or:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE import_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 2 
  AND import_date < (trunc(sysdate) - 2) + 1;
```

The parentheses aren't really required in the second expression, they are just there to document that it's the same expression as the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select trunc(sysdate) from dual;
```

Returns today's date without any time

```
select trunc(sysdate) - interval '2' day from dual;
```

Returns the day 2 days before today without time.

You can also use `month`, `hour`, `year` etc instead of `day`.

Comment: I would avoid using `interval 'x' year` at least since it is not leap-year safe

Comment: To stay save with leap years, one has to use the `add_months()`-function. Add_Year and others arent leap-year-safe as well.